# How do I convert HTML into document form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rtf, docx

I'd like to be able to convert HTML to either [docx](https://github.com/bagilevi/docx_builder) or [RTF](https://github.com/thechrisoshow/rtf/). There are plenty of Ruby gems for creating docx and RTF docs, but they are just for *creating* an empty document, which you can then programmatically add stuff to.

The issue with those gems is there is no way to accurately convert the format of a webpage to be the same/similar on a printable page.  There are a lot of complexities with HTML tags, and the position of those tags due to their CSS attributes.

With my current knowledge of the gems out there for [RTF](https://github.com/thechrisoshow/rtf/) and [Word](https://github.com/bagilevi/docx_builder) creation, I'd have to write an HTML parser and convert all the HTML tags to similar openXML tags, such as bold, and italic, but then position things based on the CSS, but due to `position: relative/absolute` rendering a document page would be extremely difficult.

I'm wondering if there are any recent developments, or if there is some soon-to-be-released gem or service or tool to be able to handle this conversion.

There is a gem that is supposed to convert Word to and from HTML, but, it has no documentation, and can only be found at https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/gems/word_parsing and on rubygems. And, I've been unsuccessful installing it on my local machine, due to dependency issues. Since there is no documentation, there is no mention how to fix the dependencies.

There are services out there that will convert PDF to "word", and converting HTML to PDF has already been solved by multiple people or gems. This service: http://www.pdftoword.com/ converts PDF to RTF, and even separates out the images in the resulting document. Their issue is that it runs on a Windows server -- I need something cross platform, because the app I'm working on is Ruby on Rails running on Unix based servers.

Comment: Have you considered looking at OpenOffice/LibreOffice's `--headless --convert-to` functionality?  Not going to post this as an answer, as I've only heard it works, never used it myself.

Comment: I have not, is that possible to have/put in gem form though?

Comment: I suppose it's conceptually possible to create a gem that might include all of the gigantic binary horribleness that is OOo/LO, but that would be rather silly.  If you can control the environment, then you can simply make sure that the proper packages are installed and the binaries are where you expect them to be during rollouts.  If you *don't* control the environment, then this is probably a non-starter.  I wouldn't expect positive reactions from sysadmins when asking them install OOo/LO on their machines.

Comment: haha, yeah. that would be a bit much to ask of them. But yeah, since I'm working with an RoR environment, all the set up is real minimal. The Server we are using is hosted by EngineYard, and just runs our code via git Pulls.

Answer (score 1):

I've published a little gem that generates `docx` files from `html` templates.

https://github.com/docxtor/docxtor

It can insert page numbers, footers/headers with given `<div>`'s contains, translate `<h1>` headings to document headings.

The catch is that all word processors parse `docx` format differently. So the resulting files are read just fine by Libre Office on Mac, but wouldn't open in Google Docs.

Any help and/or feedback on a gem is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm also looking for this kind of solution, I think it's better looking at on https://github.com/bagilevi/docx_builder. I haven't tried it yet however. Read this article also http://rubythings.blogspot.com/2011/05/creating-word-documents-in-rails.html

If someone could come up with a better solution, we all would be thankful :)